# 12 hour to 24 hour time conversion

Tags: c++, string, time

I am trying to write this c++ program from hackerrank but in my output all I am getting is a blank space.

The input string is in the form of *HH*:*MM*:*SSpp* where *HH* is an hour on two digits with leading zero, *MM* the minutes, *SS* the seconds and *pp* is either AM or PM.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string timeConversion(string s) 
{
    string p;
    int i,j;
    if(s[8]==80){                   // checking if it is AM or PM
       int x = s[0]*10 + s[1] +12;
       int y = x%10;
       int z = x/10;
       s[0]= z;
       s[1]= y;
       for(i=0;i<10;i++){
           p[i]=s[i];
       }
    }
    string newt= p.substr(0, p.size()-2);      //removing last two characters 
    return newt;
}

int main()
{ 
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));
    string s;

    getline(cin, s);                

    string result = timeConversion(s);

    fout << result << "\n";
    enter code here
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Is there some logical error? I know the other approach for this question but it would be great if anyone could help me with it.

Comment: `getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));`, Is that environment variable set somewhere by you? Like in the terminal from where you run this program?

Comment: You're confusing digits with numbers. `'1' * 10` is not 10; with ASCII encoding it's 490.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31816096/1848654

Comment: @melpomene yes, this is true. But is it relevant to the OP's specific problem ?

Comment: @JoeyMallone good question! You're right: this is risky; and the file is opened and it's not checked whether this succeeded.  But OP's result is the same if you'd output everything to cout ;-)

Comment: And if the code would work as you expect, what is your expectation for 12:15:00pm ?

Comment: @Christophe No, which is why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with treating character digits (e.g. `s[0]`) as integer digits.

If you are certain you are dealing with digits, the way to do arithmetic with the characters is by subtracting the value of the character `'0'`, like so: `s[0] - '0'`. The result will be the integral digit.

Comment: That's certainly  a valid remark!  However, OP's will continue to return an empty string despite your advice. And even for AM strings where no math needs to be done. Because p is initalized to an empty string, which makes any instruction accessing p[x] to be UB ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### The main problem

In your `timeConversion()` function, you define a  string p, which is initialized by the string default constructor to "".

Now for AM times,  you skip the `if` and go directly to `string newt= p.substr(0, p.size()-2);`, which on an empty `p` will just create an empty `newt` string.  So you return an empty value.  Every time !

For PM times, you go into the `if` to do some transformations.  Unfortunately `p[i]=s[i];` doesn't do what you think.  In fact it is out of bound access in the empty `p` string. And in the end, the length of p will still be 0 which will cause an empty value to be returned (in the best case).

### The start of a solution

Initialize `p` at construction:

```
string p=s;
```

The code will then immediately work for AM strings. For PM strings, you still need to take into account [uv_ 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54606070/3723423) related to ascii vs. binary math.

Here the result:

```
string timeConversion(string s) 
{
    string p=s;
    int i,j;
    if(s[8]=='P'){                   // checking if it is AM or PM
       int x =(s[0]-'0')*10 + (s[1]-'0') +12;
       p[0]= x/10 +'0';
       p[1]= x%10 +'0';
    }
    return p.substr(0, p.size()-2);   //removing last two characters 
}
```

***Note:*** this assumes that the entry format will always be valid, and no space will be used instead of a leading 0.

***Important Note:*** This code will fail on hackerrank, because it transforms 12:15:00pm into 24:15:00  and not in 12:15:00.  Furthermore 12:00:00am  will be tranformed in 12:00:00 instead of 00:00:00.  More on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock).  [Online demo](https://ideone.com/HcvSTn) about how to address these special cases

Answer (score 0):

**This code will work considering all test cases, just added two more conditions.**

```
string timeConversion(string s)
{
       string ans=s;
       if(ans[8]=='P')
       {
           int x = (ans[0]-'0')*10+(ans[1]-'0')+12;
           //cout<<x;
           if(x!=24)
           {
                ans[0]=x/10+'0';
                ans[1]=x%10+'0';
           }
       }
       if(ans[8]=='A')
       {
           int y=(ans[0]-'0')*10+ans[1]-'0';
           if(y==12)
           {
               ans[0]='0';
               ans[1]='0';
           }
       }
    return ans.substr(0, ans.size()-2);
}
```